# Why is there a preference to use the cumulative distribution function to characterise a random variable instead of the probability density function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Perhaps this is but a subtlety but I've noticed that in quite a few definitions in statistics and probability, definitions regarding the distribution of a variable or a sample of data choose to use the cumulative distribution function to characterise random variables as following a specific distribution as opposed to using the probability density function.

E.g with the Kolmogorov Smirnov test, we look at the difference between cdfs and not pdfs.

Is there a specific reason for this ?

Comment: because densities doesn't exists in general, however the distribution of a random variable ever exists

Comment: Singular distributions.

Comment: As a practical matter, it's a lot easier to transform a variable using its cumulative distribution than it is to use its probability density. There are just fewer things you have to remember correctly. That's why I personally prefer them. I suspect there are deeper reasons if you're actually going into the theory, though.

Answer (score 36):

Every random variable has a CDF. Not every random variable has a pdf (for instance, discrete or mixtures of discrete and continuous distributions). For instance, in the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, you are comparing an empirical CDF, which is discrete, to a potentially continuous CDF. In addition, [convergence in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution) is defined using CDFs.

Comment: I would however argue that **a)** every random variable does have a probability density, just it's not always a _function_, **b)** while it is always possible to give a CDF, .this requires the domain to be ordered, for which there is in general no straightforward way (in particular for multidimensional continuous distributions).

Comment: [Multivariate CDFs exist.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Multivariate_case)

Comment: That requires an (in general arbitrary) coordinate convention.

Comment: So does a multivariate pdf, so that's not really an argument against CDFs.

Comment: @leftaroundabout This answer concerns PDF's and every PDF(=Probability Density **Function**) is of course a function. I have really no idea what you mean by saying that every random variable has a probability density, and that in some cases that is **no function**. Then what on earth is it?...

Comment: @drhab it's a _distribution_. This can be formalised perfectly well in the framework of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), and in such a way that allows describing discrete random variables on a continuous space (cf. [Dirac distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_distribution)), and ...

Comment: ... @kccu no it doesn't require any arbitrary coordinate choice. (Or, as physicists prefer to see it, it is _well-behaved under any coordinate transformation_, which is not the case for multivariate CDFs.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout So there is no difference between a density and a distribution?.., IMV you are at least broadening this subject too much and mention things here that have not been in mind of the OP by asking this question.

Comment: Hm. leftaroundabout's point about distributions has me thinking: it would be interesting to know if there was a nice theory of PDFs as hyperfunctions, as they both famously fail to multiply: the $f(x)~g(x)$ which worked for PMFs is no longer meaningful as a PDF, and multiplication cannot be done in general with hyperfunctions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout This question is about statistics, not physics.

Comment: @CRDrost yes! Well, it's not much of a theory, but it can be made sense of. Basically, a distribution boils down to a _dual vector_ on a space of continuous functions, $u\in (\mathcal{C}^0(X)\to\mathbb{R})$. The continuous functions themselves form a commutative algebra (i.e. they support point-wise multiplication $f\cdot g \equiv x\mapsto f(x)\cdot g(x)$), but the dual vectors do not. It is, however, possible to multiply a distribution with a continuous function to yield another distribution: $u\cdot f := g \mapsto \langle u, f\cdot g\rangle$.

Comment: Mixture distributions have densities whenever the mixture components have densities.  Maybe remove the  " or mixture distributions" from the answer, to not muddy the waters?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I think your latest comment illustrates nicely why CDF's are preferred to PDF's! (Which was, after all, the question.)

Answer (score 20):

You pretty much always want to calculate Pr(a < x < b), which is a simple subtraction if you have a CDF. If you're using a PDF, you have to integrate, which is a very complex operation.

Comment: Simple as that, this is IMO the best argument. Though of course the same caveat as for the other answers applies: _this only works for 1D distributions_. For continuous distributions on a higher-dimensional domain, CDF is not straightforward at all, neither to define nor to use.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Also for random vectors we have CDF's. Maybe less easy to use but defined on a straightforward and proper way.

Comment: Maybe we should note that $P(a < X \leq b) = F(b) - F(a)$ (where $F$ is the CDF of $X$). If $X$ is not continuous, then using $F$ to compute $P(a < X < b)$ is not quite so simple.

Answer (score 17):

The CDF of a random variable completely determines the distribution of a random variable.

The PDF of a random variable completely determines the distribution of a random variable.

---

So uptil here no differences, but they arise if we look at the converse of these statements.

The distribution of a random variable is determining for its CDF, or - in other words - *there is only one CDF*.

This cannot be said about PDF.

Observe for instance that for uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ we can use several PDF's. The most common one is the indicator function of $[0,1]$ but another is the indicator function of $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q^{\complement}$.

---

The CDF of a random variable *always exists*.

The PDF of a random variable *does not always exist*.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. The PDF _is_ unique outside of a Lebesgue null set. You want to argue that the CDF is unique _everywhere_, but it isn't for the cases where the distinction is actually important, namely discrete distributions. The CDF of, say, the outcomes of a dice throw seen in $\mathbb{R}$ is defined uniquely almost everywhere, but at e.g. 2 it is undefined within the range $[\frac16,\frac13]$, at 4 undefined within $[\tfrac23,\tfrac56]$ etc..

Comment: @lelftaroundabout For **every** real-valued random variable $X$ and **every** $x\in\mathbb R$ the event $\{X\leq x\}$ is measurable so that $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$ exists, is (of course) unique and is properly defined. What you are saying about the CDF of a random variable that represents the outcome of the roll of a die makes no sense at all. If the die is fair then in that case $F_X(2)=P(X=1)+P(X=2)=\frac26$.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Further on your first point if $f,g$ are both Pdf's of the same distribution then the set $\{f\neq g\}$ is a Borel set with Lebesgue measure $0$. I do not deny that in my answer but just remark that we do not necessarily have $f=g$. Why do you label that as something that doesn't really make sense?...

Comment: @leftaroundabout For completeness: CDF as used in my answer is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Definition).

Comment: Don't really understand the confusion; this is pretty much a complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

The values of a CDF are probabilities, and thus easy to directly reason about. On the other hand the values of a PDF (when it exists) have no direct intuitive meaning but are instead characterized less directly by the property that when you integrate over a set you get the probability of being in that set. That is a little harder to reason about. CDFs are thus more intuitive than PDFs.

On the other hand, in the discrete case both CDFs and PMFs can be directly interpreted as probabilities, with the PMF giving the probability of a simpler event. In such situations the PMF is often both easier to work with and perhaps more intuitive.

Comment: The values of the PDF can be thought of as "probability per X", where X is the unit of the domain.

Answer (score -1):

A CDF behaves straightforwardly under transformation/substitution of variables while a PDF requires meddling with differential coefficients.